# Why don't I have a hat anymore?

Tags: escape-goat-2

I got the hat in the forest, I was able to use it in the Excavation, then I moved into the Library, and I now I don't have it anymore.

Is that normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entering the Parish I suddenly found the Hat again, so I guess you have to find it again in each world before you can use it.

---

*Consider this a provisional answer, I'll update if I have any news, and I'll delete it if someone comes up with a more complete knowledge.*